# Android saving ImageView in App State

Tags: android, imageview, state

I have made an Android App that gets an XML feed (off a website) loops through it and displays the images in the feed.

I am using a "Gallery" and an "Image Adapter" to display all images - loading them from the website (as the feed supplies a URL)

But when ever the phone changes oriantation the application re-sets itself and the state is lost - causing the feed to be consumed again and the images to be re-loaded (which is very big on the bandwidth)

In the ImageAdapter I have created an array of ImageView objects that allows me to retain the images loaded from the website on a local object (so not to load them again)

But since the application is re-set every time the phone changes orientation the object array gets erased and everything loads backup again.

I'm trying to save this ImageView array in the App State but can't find the right function???

Here is the code:

```
package com.test;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    private String[] mImageIds = {};
    private String[] titles = {};
    public ImageView[] images = {};

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;

        try{
            //open local file and parse to XML  
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc;

            doc = docBuilder.parse(mContext.openFileInput("xmlfeed.xml"));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList itms = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            String temp = "";
            String tempTitles = "";

            //loop through xml items to retreive all nodes
            for (int i = 0; i < itms.getLength(); i++){
                Node itm = itms.item(i);
                if(temp==""){
                    temp = getTagValue(itm, "image");
                    tempTitles = getTagValue(itm, "title");
                }else{
                    temp = temp + "," + getTagValue(itm, "image");
                    tempTitles = tempTitles + "," + getTagValue(itm, "title");
                }
            }
            mImageIds = temp.split(",");
            titles = tempTitles.split(",");

            //create all images as empty vars
            if(images.length==0){
                images = new ImageView[itms.getLength()];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //loads the image in case it does not already exists in the object
        if(images[position]==null){
            ImageView imgs = new ImageView(mContext);
            try{
                imgs.setImageDrawable(drawable_from_url(mImageIds[position], "src"));
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imgs.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            images[position] = imgs;
        }
        return images[position];
    }

    Drawable drawable_from_url(String url, String src_name) throws java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException{
        Toast.makeText(mContext, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), src_name);
    }

    public String getTagValue(Node itm, String tagName){
        String title_value = "";
        if (itm.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        {
            Element itmElm = (Element) itm;
            NodeList title = itmElm.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
            Element titleElm = (Element) title.item(0);
            NodeList title_nodes = titleElm.getChildNodes();
            title_value = ((Node) title_nodes.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim();
        }
        return title_value;
    }
}
```

Please help, how would I go about saving this in the App State???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your listview is defined inside oncreate() method of Activity A. 
Do the followings to that activity to make your UIfreeze in screen orientation

Add the following to the activity declaration in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

so it looks like

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
        android:name=".your.package">
```

The matter is that the system destroys the activity when a change in the configuration occurs.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: This works - thanks, although I was a bit more concerned about trying to save the ImageView Array into the App State...